# Chrome mobile adding a Forwarded header

Tags: android, google-chrome, http, mobile, http-headers

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with my Chrome Mobile on an Android LG phone.

A website I'm working on is facing `conflict with "FORWARDED" and "X_FORWARDED_FOR" headers` errors which break its rendering.

**My website logs are trustfull : my Chrome Mobile is responsible for that !**

Switching to private nav or using another browser, I do not trigger the error.

Application side, we fixed the problem by removing the unwanted `FORWARDED` header.

I cleared my Chrome app caches (history, websites parameters, app cache...) and I forced data sync on my Google account.

But I still do not understand why my Chrome mobile is adding this `FORWARDED` header.

Comment: Is there a `Via:` header?

Comment: Yes, indeed : `Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy` and thi `Via` header is not present in private browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it !

I enabled "Data saver" functionality on my Chrome Mobile (see "Settings" > "Data Saver"). This enables the use of a Google Proxy which seems to add the `Forwarded` header. Look at my requests seen by my Varnish reverse-proxy :

```
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    Forwarded: for=90.14.196.122
-   BereqHeader    Save-Data: on
-   BereqHeader    Scheme: http
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: http
-   BereqHeader    Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 90.14.196.122, 66.249.93.220, xxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxx
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 1016435
```

While browsing private :

```
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-   BereqHeader    Save-Data: on
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    Surrogate-Capability: abc=ESI/1.0
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 90.14.196.122, xxxxxxxxxxx, xxxxxxxxxxx
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 997420
```

Then, turning "Data saver" off does the trick.